# React data loading the previous state than what it is supposed to

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following app structure for my application: App.js -> Filter.js -> ListModal.js. The data for me is a JSON containing table names as keys, with individual columns corresponding to these keys.
The Filter.js contains a search bar, which upon clicking loads up the ListModal, showing a list of 'table names' depending upon what's typed in the search bar. Upon selecting a particular table name, the name along with corresponding data has to go back to App.js, which then passes it on to other modules.

The Filter.js:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const allTableName = Object.keys(data)
    allTableNames.forEach((key,value)=>{
      if(key.toUpperCase().includes(phyName.toUpperCase())){     //phyName contains the user input
         searchedTables.push(key)
      })
      setSearchedTables(searchedTables)
}, [searchedTables])

const fetchTables = () => {    //Called upon clicking 'Submit' on the search bar
    setSearchedTables([])
    tableListModalShower()     //to show the modal
}

const setTable = (selectedTablename) => {
    setTableDataToReturn(data[selectedTablename])    //variable to maintain which table's data to pass to parent App.js component
    props.tableToPassInfo(selectedTablename, tableDataToReturn)
}

<ListModal searchedTables={searchedTables} onSelect={setTable}/>   // To load the modal
```

The Modal body:

```
<Modal.body>
    props.searchedTables.map(t=>(
        <li key={t} value={t} onClick={() =>{ props.onSelect(t)}}>{t}</li>
    )) 
</Modal.body>
```

App.js:

```
const [table, setTable] = useState({"tableName":"", "tableInfo":""})
const tableToPassInfo = (tablename, table) => {
    setTable({"tableName":tablename, "tableInfo":table})
    console.log(table)    //Here, I get the data for the table I searched for in the previous search, not the current one. Also, I do not get anything in the table name 
}

<FilterSection tableToPassInfo={tableToPassInfo}/>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why am I getting the previous state of what I selected from the 'List Modal'? Any help is appreciated. Happy to provide more details if required!

Comment: setTable is asynchronous so it may not update before the console.log, you can monitor changes to the state in a useEffect: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html.
There's also an extra '>' in the FilterSection call and "tableName" is all lower case in 'setTable' which may affect the initiation of the state.

Comment: Ah sorry, those were typos, my bad. Have corrected them. However, I'm not getting the 'table' state correctly in the App.js, and I need it there to pass it on to other components. How can I resolve it? If I'm getting the wrong state in the console, there's a high chance I would get the wrong state in the components I'm gonna pass this data to, isnt it?

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that there are two table variables in App.js, one for state and another as the method parameter. Unsure off the top of my head which takes precedence but I would rename the method parameter

Comment: Sorry for splitting the responses up - on props.tableToPassInfo use data[selectedTableName] rather than tableDataToReturn as that will also suffer from the state async issue

Comment: This did solve the issue where I'm not getting the table name in the 'table' state. However  the response is still coming one click later

Answer (score 1):

I've done my best to update the code based on the comments

The Filter.js:

```
// I removed the useEffect on searchTables as it was set to run on change but was also changing within that method.
    
const fetchTables = () => {                    
    const allTableName = Object.keys(data)
    allTableNames.forEach((key,value)=>{
        if(key.toUpperCase().includes(phyName.toUpperCase())){     
             searchedTables.push(key);
        }
    });
                  
    setSearchedTables(searchedTables)
    tableListModalShower()     //to show the modal
}
            
const setTable = (selectedTablename) => {
    setTableDataToReturn(data[selectedTablename]);    
    props.tableToPassInfo(selectedTablename, data[selectedTablename]);
}
            
<ListModal searchedTables={searchedTables} onSelect={setTable}/>
```

The Modal body:

```
<Modal.body>
    props.searchedTables.map(t=>(
        <li key={t} value={t} onClick={() =>{ props.onSelect(t)}}>{t}</li>
    )) 
</Modal.body>
```

App.js:

```
const [table, setTable] = useState({"tableName":"", "tableInfo":""})
const tableToPassInfo = (tablename, tableinfo) => {
    setTable({"tableName":tablename, "tableInfo":tableinfo})
    console.log(tableinfo)    
}

<FilterSection tableToPassInfo={tableToPassInfo}/>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for writing up this answer! I tried it out, however, I'm still getting the previous state in my App.js :/

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest now, I would perhaps debug each step to check the correct data is being passed through e.g. pop a console.log above 
props.tableToPassInfo(selectedTablename, data[selectedTablename]);
to check the onSelect, then work my way backwards.

Comment: No probs man. Thank you for trying out! I tried out these but to no avail.